# Error unmarshalling JSON in Go that starts with an Array

Tags: json, go

This is my code

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "log"
)

type Data struct {
    Page          int
    Pages         int
    PerPage       string
    Total         int
    CountriesList []Country
}
type Country struct {
    Id  string
    Iso string
}

func main() {
    body := []byte(`[
    {
        "page": 1,
        "pages": 6,
        "per_page": "50",
        "total": 256
    },
    [
        {
            "id": "ABW",
            "iso2Code": "AW"}]]`)

    items := make([]Data, 10)

    if err := json.Unmarshal(body, &items); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("error %v", err)
    }
}
```

I'm try to unmarshall some JSON and getting the following error:
**error json: cannot unmarshal array into Go value of type main.Data**

Answer (score 2):

When reading the question, I assumed that there could be multiple Data + list of Country pairs. Here's the solution I ended up with:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
)

type Data struct {
    Page    int
    Pages   int
    PerPage string `json:"per_page, string"`
    Total   int
}
type Country struct {
    Id       string
    Iso2Code string
}

type DataCountry struct {
    Data        Data
    CountryList []Country
}

func main() {
    body := []byte(`[
    {
        "page": 1,
        "pages": 6,
        "per_page": "50",
        "total": 256
    },
    [
        {
            "id": "ABW",
            "iso2Code": "AW"}]
]`)

    raw := make([]json.RawMessage, 10)
    if err := json.Unmarshal(body, &raw); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("error %v", err)
    }

    sdc := make([]DataCountry, 0)
    for i := 0; i < len(raw); i += 2 {
        dc := DataCountry{}

        data := Data{}
        if err := json.Unmarshal(raw[i], &data); err != nil {
            fmt.Println("error %v", err)
        } else {
            dc.Data = data
        }

        var countries []Country
        if err := json.Unmarshal(raw[i+1], &countries); err != nil {
            fmt.Println("error %v", err)
        } else {
            dc.CountryList = countries
        }

        sdc = append(sdc, dc)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", sdc)
}
```

I found the blog post ["Using go to unmarshal json lists with multiple types"](http://mattyjwilliams.blogspot.com/2013/01/using-go-to-unmarshal-json-lists-with.html) very useful for understanding several different options for dealing parsing JSON lists.

Answer (score 1):

```
package main

import (
        "encoding/json"
        "fmt"
        "log"
)

type Data struct {
        Page          int
        Pages         int
        Per_Page      string
        Total         int
        CountriesList []Country
}
type Country struct {
        Id       string
        Iso2Code string
}

func main() {
        body := []byte(`
        [
                {
                        "page": 1,
                        "pages": 6,
                        "per_page": "50",
                        "total": 256,
                        "countrieslist": [
                                {
                                    "id": "ABW",
                                    "iso2Code": "AW"
                                }
                        ]
                }
        ]
`)

        items := make([]Data, 10)

        if err := json.Unmarshal(body, &items); err != nil {
                log.Fatalf("error %v", err)
        }

        fmt.Printf("%#v\n", items)
}
```

[Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/j31GeKSPOQ)

---

Output:

```
[]main.Data{main.Data{Page:1, Pages:6, Per_Page:"50", Total:256, CountriesList:[]main.Country{main.Country{Id:"ABW", Iso2Code:"AW"}}}}
```

Comment: Your answer uses a modified version of the JSON, not the original one

Comment: @jwesonga: Your JSON data are not (directly) compatible with the Go types you designed. You must either adapt the JSON to the Go data structures used or vice versa. Who can know which way you prefer? ;-)

Comment: Original json but modify the struct, I think the CountriesList should be turned Into a slice.. I'm nowhere near a computer to test this out though..

Answer (score 1):

I got some help from #go-nuts on IRC:

```
package main


import (
  "encoding/json"
  "fmt"
  "log"
)

type T1 struct {
  Page, Pages, Total int
  PerPage            int `json:"per_page,string"`
}

type T2 struct {
  ID       string
  ISO2Code string
}

func main() {
  body := []byte(`
    [
      {
        "page": 1,
        "pages": 6,
        "per_page": "50",
        "total": 256
      },
      [
        {
          "id": "ABW",
          "iso2Code": "AW"
        },
        {
          "id": "AFG",
          "iso2Code": "AF"
        }
      ]
    ]
  `)

  t1 := T1{}
  t2 := []T2{}

  if err := json.Unmarshal(body, &[]interface{}{&t1, &t2}); err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("error %v", err)
  }

  fmt.Printf("%#v  %#v", t1, t2)
  for k, v := range t2 {
    fmt.Printf("%v %v\n",k, v.ID)
  }
}
```